# Dynamic Child Class generation - PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, autoload

I have an abstract "object" class that provides basic CRUD functionality along with validation, etc.  Typically I would use the __autoload($name) magic function to load a class that would exist in its own file, named the same as the class I wish to lazy load.  The code would look something like this, which as you can imagine becomes quite repetitive.

```
final class bicycle extends object {
    public function __construct($id=null) {
      parent::__construct($id, __CLASS__);
    }
    public function __toString() {
      return($this->name);
    }
}
```

My question is whether or not I can somehow dynamically generate these classes on the fly so I don't have to create the same functionality over and over - thus reducing overhead and design time.  Does PHP5 even support this or am I simply overestimating the power of OO PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality does not exist in PHP5.  It may be available in PHP6, but since there is no package for ubuntu yet I will not proceed.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of copy-pasting this, why don't you just put the code of the `__construct` and `__toString` methods in the definition of your `object` class ?

Something like this should do :

```
class object {
    public function __construct($id = null) {
        $this->name = get_class($this);
    }
    public function __toString() {
      return($this->name);
    }
    protected $name;
}

final class bicycle extends object {

}
```

And, calling it :

```
$a = new bicycle();
var_dump($a);
```

You get :

```
object(bicycle)[1]
  protected 'name' => string 'bicycle' (length=7)
```

Which means an instance of class `bicycle`, with the name `property` at the right value.

No need to copy-paste any code -- except for the definition of the `bicycle` class itself.

As a sidenote, if you really want to generate a class dynamically, you can probably use something like this :

```
$code = 'final class bicycle extends object {}';
eval($code);
```

You just have to construct the `$code` variable dynamically.

But **I would strongly advise against this** :

- you will not have code assist in your IDE, as it cannot see the class
- you will not have phpdoc for your class *(same reason)*
- there is always the "*eval is evil*" stuff -- and that's quite true, at least in this situation.
- using "`new bicycle`" without having declared the class feels wrong !
- there's gotta be some performance implication with the use of `eval`

Declaring a new class is not such a pain, and I would definitly prefer copy-pasting-modifying a few line than use anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for __toString, you just put it in the parent class. Example follows:

```
class BaseObject {
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class bicycle extends BaseObject {
}

$b = new bicycle();
$b->name = 'foo';
echo $b;
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish with overriding the constructor to pass in **CLASS**.

Comment: The child class passes it's name to the parent's constructor to be run through a series of tests and eventually, using a naming system, it determines the table name (if exists) and sort of provides an automated rails-esque scaffold environment.  This saves me a lot of time at work as I have to come up with basic small apps to appease some manager. :)